# How to get the parent node of a value in XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Below is my XML file and function to get the parent node using a value. But I am struck to get the parent node.

When the value 133 is passed to function it should return "firstnode" 
and when 124 is passed to  function it should return "secondnode"

How can I do this? I am using vb.net, but I can use C# too.

My XML file:

```
<sample>
    <firstnode>
        <id>133</id>
    </firstnode>
    <secondnode>
        <id>124</id>
    </secondnode>
</sample>
```

My function in vb.net :

```
Public Shared Function Get_NodeName_by_ID(ByVal ID As String) As String
    Dim value As String = "" 
    Dim strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("app_settings").ToString())
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(strPath) 

    Return value
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

XPath provides you facility to manipulate XML Document as per your requirement.
Use below XPath expression to do this, and sorry my code is in C# so, you need to convert it in vb.

XPath Expression: sample/*[id=133]

C# Code:

```
//Load FileXML
XmlDocument objFileXML = new XmlDocument();

objFileXML .Load(sFilePath);

//For selecting nodes having given value
XmlNodeList lstNodes = objFileXML .SelectNodes("sample/*[id=133]");
```

Note: you can put any variable if you want to put value dynamically. It will be just in your vb code.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: lstNodes.Count always returns 0. I have used the same code as above. What would be the problem ?

Comment: Please, make sure that xml file structure is same as provided above. I've tried it on my side and it returns 1. And debug your project, to check whether objFileXML loads file correctly. If it loads file correctly then it must find nodes with value 133.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worker for me.

```
 Dim strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("settings").ToString())
            Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
            doc.Load(strPath)

        Dim ParentNode As XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("id")
        For Each node As XmlNode In ParentNode 
            If (ID.Equals(node.ChildNodes(0).Value)) Then
                value = node.ParentNode.Name.ToString()
            End If 
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

While there may indeed be relatively obscure means to get your desired answer/result via a myriad of XML processing technologies, never overlook the simplicity and speed of low-level methodologies.

The logic of the submitted foreach iteration looks excellent to me, but I don't have the time to test it. Nonetheless the author asserts they have done so; a cursory look finds its logic appears to be sound; and I am sure anyone who chooses to deploy it will soon discover its worthiness. It may be a gem.

But the reason I believe an alternate solution should be offered is, that while we have to respect the intimate wherewithal that can provide such answers, *our* position, whenever we encounter such seeming difficulties, is a lack of such intimate knowledge (or we wouldn't have the question). Finding a high-level method to solve our problems very often requires a great deal of research and thinking before we chance to have such prospective solutions fall into our lap; and, having specific intentions in their designs, they often may not produce exactly the results we are after. I regularly see the efforts of finding and mastering such methodologies far exceed the work of engineering a proper method ourselves.

To avoid these higher costs then, we should first conjure how to accomplish the object of the cited sophistications ourselves. Having done substantial work with flat-file databases *way back* in the past, it strikes me that simple text-file processing methods will readily solve your problem. However, the potential success of the following suggested approach depends upon inviolable adherence to the format of the XML data supplied with your question.

Because the object of your question requires identifying the contents of XML *tags*, you can solve your problem very simply by searching your XML file, not for "*133*," but instead for "*>133<*". If it's possible for example that white space might inadvertently be included in the tag (as in "> 133 <" for example), you might use a regex search to resolve such potential disparities. However, properly generated files should not possess such prospective aberrations. Nonetheless, it is incumbent upon you to foresee such possibilities, and account for them in circumstances where they *can* exist. As regex will slow your search down (as parallel functionalities will slow the searches of XML facilities), avoid the additional overhead and tedium of regex, if regex is not required.

In any case, if the file is written to the standards of your careful question (which properly presents the value without white space), you can simply search the file for ">133<" (eliminating the possibility of erroneously processing "123133", "13345", etc.).

Get the position of your successful find in your file, and next, parse the following characters until you discover the first instance of "</" — thereafter collecting the following characters only, up to but not including the very next ">".

This simple and routine practice will yield your requested answers, "firstnode", and "secondnode" respectively.

Likely, any higher-level methodology might even be a tad slower, or require more overhead (although the results for both should be virtually instantaneous on small-to-medium files), because, for example, the XML facility might customarily find and process both the beginning and ending tags — plus detect and remove potential white space if it recognizes the field represents an integer. We often don't really know how such internal functions work, but from observed behaviors. Yet, of necessity, high-level facilities often perform operations which are dispensable to the explicit objects of our applications.

Thus, granting that the binary methods for processing text files have long been optimized, your carefully-written low-level approach should offer maximum speed... even if this is really only a consideration in extremely large files. Speed always bespeaks efficiency and ideal coding practice. What's important to understand is, that your low-level process will probably be at least as fast as using a high-level XML facility you might never find on your own — and may not master in the time you can write a simple low-level procedure.